# WSO2 - Transforming and aggregating different JSON data from multiple endpoints

Tags: json, rest, wso2, wso2-esb

I've created an API in WSO2 Carbon (5.0) which I POST a payload to:

`{ 
    "IdNumber" : "8008185218088", 
    "LastName" : null
}`

I then call initiate a clone mediator sequence which forwards this payload to two different REST endpoints. The json response from the endpoints is different:

Endpoint 1 response:

`{
   "Name" : "Daniel",
   "Number" : "12345678"
}`

Endpoint 2 response:

`{
   "Name": "Bob",
   "Address": "200 Bob Street",
   "Code": "123"
}`

The API response I'd like to create based on the above:

```
{
   "Endpoint 1 Response" : {
        "Name" : "Daniel",
        "Number" : "12345678"
   },

   "Endpoint 2 Response" : {
        "Name": "Bob",
        "Address": "200 Bob Street",
        "Code": "123"
   }
}
```

What mediators on the `outSequence` do I need to configure to achieve this? How would I query the individual json response fields and combine them into a custom formatted json message for the client?

I've looked at the Aggregate mediator but I don't think it's right for differently formatted messages.

Here is my inSequence for reference:

```
   <resource methods="POST">
      <inSequence>
         <property name="ROOT" scope="default">
            <root:rootelement xmlns:root="www.wso2esb.com"/>
         </property>
         <log level="full"/>
         <clone continueParent="true" id="test" sequential="true">
            <target>
               <sequence>
                  <send>
                     <endpoint>
                        <address uri="http://192.168.1.1/api/service/person" format="rest"/>
                     </endpoint>
                  </send>
               </sequence>
            </target>
            <target>
               <sequence>
                  <send>
                     <endpoint>
                        <address uri="http://192.168.1.1/api2/query" format="rest"/>
                     </endpoint>
                  </send>
               </sequence>
            </target>
         </clone>
      </inSequence>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will be unable to aggregate messages like this. A solution is to use the 'call' mediator, store the first response (or the values) in a property and call the second service afterwards.

Something like this:

```
<call>
   <endpoint>
       <address uri="http://192.168.1.1/api/service/person" format="rest"/>
   </endpoint>
</call>
<property name="Name1" expression="//Name" />
<property name="Number1" expression="//Number" />
<send>
   <endpoint>
       <address uri="http://192.168.1.1/api2/query" format="rest"/>
   </endpoint>
</send>
<outSequence>
-- build message using payloadfactory
</outSequence>
```

You can use a [payloadFactory](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/PayloadFactory+Mediator) in the outSequence to build the response message.

Comment: Looks like a good solution, just a few questions. Why use a call in the first mediator and then send in the second one? Also, how do I tell the difference between a property for a field on the first call if the field name is the same on the 2nd endpoint response, such as my "Name" json field?

Comment: Hi Daniel, Normally a proxyservice passes the request trough the insequence using 'send' and the response through the outsequence using send'. In this case you want to do 2 requests so the additional one is done using 'call'. To answer your second question: the mediator operates always on the 'message context' meaning the current message that is being processed. So after the call you will operate on the response of the first api call and after the send (in the outsequence) you operate on the response of the second api call.

Comment: Thanks Jan. The problem I'm experiencing using your solution is that the outSequence seems to be executing before the response from the 2nd endpoint is received. Also, I'm not sure how to handle the situation where both properties use the same expression (because both responses have the same field name), but different values. How do I ensure both responses are received before the outSequence is executed, and how do I define 2 properties with the same expression for the 2 different responses?

Comment: Hmm, this should not be the case but I must admit I am mostly working with soap services and not with rest. One tip: set configure->logging-> synapse.transport.http.wire to debug, this helps with finding out what is going on. Also if you want to try an alternate solution you could use a 'call' on the first and second rest service and end the insequence with a <respond/>. This should give the same result.